# disable space after colon

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to disable the automatic addition of spaces after colons in CSS?

Comment: [This guide from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Writing_guidelines/Writing_style_guide/Code_style_guide/CSS#syntax_style) suggests keeping the space after colons, for readability. (technically, its for code examples on the site but it is good practice)

Comment: I agree with the previous comment, but curious why the single space matters? ... is it causing an issue?